# Find and replace using regex in Notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++, wildcard

I am trying to figure out how to change these three lines in Notepad++ from this

```
foo('a');
foo('b');
foo('c');
```

to this

```
foo('a',new=>'4');
foo('b',new=>'4');
foo('c',new=>'4');
```

//(foo)(

Comment: Have you tried a pattern like `(foo\([^\)]+)` with a replacement of `\1,new=>'4'`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the Menu Bar, then Search, then Replace.
2. Ensure that "Search Mode" is set to regex.
3. Enter the following into "Find what": `\\)`
4. Enter the following into "Replace with": `\\, new=>\'4\'\)`
5. Press the "Replace All" button